# How to set a particular colorspace for the output in imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick-convert

How to control the colorspace in the output file using convert. I tried

```
convert __targets/test_pattern_raw.png -set colorspace RGB -depth 16 -colorspace RGB PNG64:__targets/test_pattern.png
```

First I set colorspace to RGB, because the input file has falsely been tagged as sRGB. Now I want to save the image in linear space as well. However, the command above gives a non-linear image:

```
identify __targets/test_pattern.png
```

> __targets/test_pattern.png PNG 1600x1000 1600x1000+0+0 16-bit **sRGB** 78794B 0.000u 0:00.000

When saving in EXR format, it becomes linear, because EXR does not support anything else, but I need it to work for png, and also for rgba (which is a dump without any headers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a bug in ImageMagick. After the fix

```
convert -set colorspace RGB __targets/test_pattern_raw.png -depth 16 PNG64:__targets/test_pattern.png
```

Works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

It should work by simply using -colorspace RGB in Imagemagick.

Input:

[image]

```
 Filename: lena.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 256x256+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
```

```
convert lena.png -colorspace RGB x.png
```

```
 Filename: x.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 256x256+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Colorspace: RGB
```

Comment: So you cannot do it in one command? I have to first stamp input data, and then convert it back to linear?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean by "stamp"

Comment: Post and image and tell me what processing you need to do with it.

Comment: With "stamp" I mean "-set colorspace RGB", to force it read the input as-if it were linear. Because the input image happens to be wrong.

Comment: Can you post an example image for which you cannot just use -colorspace RGB before the output?